# Recreate GitHub's language list using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I recreate GitHub's repositories language list using CSS only? Something like this, for example:

[image]

I started with a list of `div`s but I cannot figure out how to draw the dots using CSS...

```
<div>
  <div>C 90%</div>
  <div>Assembly 5.8%</div>
  <div>Makefile 2.9%</div>
  <div>C++ 0.5%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Please read [ask] and show some effort in trying to solve this yourself and come back when you have a specific problem in your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::before` pseudo element to add the dots before each item.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Something like this:

```css
div > div {
position: relative;
margin-left: 10px;
}

div > div:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
height: 5px;
width: 5px;
right: 100%;
margin-right: 5px;
top: calc(50% - 2.5px);
border-radius: 2px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>C 90%</div>
  <div>Assembly 5.8%</div>
  <div>Makefile 2.9%</div>
  <div>C++ 0.5%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to do something similar:

```html
<div class="rows">
  <div class="dot" style="color: #555555;"></div>
  <div class="child">C 90%</div>
</div>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="dot" style="color: #6E4C13;"></div>
  <div class="child">Assembly 5.8%</div>
</div>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="dot" style="color: #427819;"></div>
  <div class="child">Makefile 2.9%</div>
</div>
```

```css
.rows {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dot, .child {
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
}

.rows > .dot {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rows > .dot:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  top: 20%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}
```

The *dot* colour is managed from the style attribute. The last thing left to do is to change the font of the language name(e.g. *Assembly*) and of the percentage(e.g. *5.8%*), after that result is very similar to GitHub's.